# Implementing RSA encryption/decryption

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA encryption/decryption (a simple implementation of course, so there's no need for nitpicking) and it seems like the numbers (i.e. the keys) are fine, yet the final result is wrong.

Here's the problematic function:

```
def square_and_mult(base, k, mod):
    b = 1
    for ki in reversed(k):
        if ki == '0':
            b = (b**2) % mod
        else:
            b = ((b**2) * base) % mod
    return b
```

Comment: Hey OliOliver... to prevent potential downvotes or close-votes here at StackOverflow, it might be a good idea to [**drop a relevant snippet of your sourcecode into your question with an edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42989207/edit). That way, others having the same problem like you might (or might not) find it easier to detect this Q&A via search engines et al. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect something is wrong with your modular exponentiation algorithm. As you're using python you can use the builtin `pow(base, exp, mod)` to do this, no need to implement it yourself.

```
In [1]: n = 48961353722289327881

In [2]: e = 7

In [3]: d = 6994479101184233143

In [4]: x = 12345678

In [5]: c = pow(x, e, n)

In [6]: c
Out[6]: 32225547235202030473

In [7]: m = pow(c, d, n)

In [8]: m
Out[8]: 12345678
```

Comment: More concretely, the issue is in the line `for ki in reversed(k):` Simply removing the `reversed` makes it work.

Comment: Thanks puzzlepalace!